# How to compact a list of numbers in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table, with one `int` column. The numbers are all unique, but not all present in the range from the least (1) to the greatest. I would like to "compact" the number list, so that the largest number in the list is the `COUNT` of numbers in the list, and that the records remain in the same relative order (think of this as an Identity column, but it actually isn't). So *e.g.* if I have the numbers

```
1 3 5 6 10 11 14 15 20 30
```

I would like them to be renumbered

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Where the 3 got changed to a 2, 5 was changed to a 3, etc. How can I do this in T-SQL?

Comment: I did not downvote, but:  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Himanshu was spot on with row_number(), already +1.

However, just in case you were looking to perform an **UPDATE**  ... this can be done via a CTE

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
    Select *
          ,NewValue = row_number() over (order by SomeCol)
     from YourTable
)
Update cte set SomeCol=NewValue
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you just need row_number()

```
    SELECT row_number() 
     over
  (partition by column order by column 
   asc) rn from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that the Numbers are already UNIQUE,
Use the below alternate methods-

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#SampleTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SampleTable

Create table #SampleTable (num int)

insert into #SampleTable values (1),(3),(5),(6),(10),(11),(14),(15),(20),(30)

--Alternate Methods
select num,
row_number() over (order by num) as [ROW_NUMBER],
rank() over (order by num) as [RANK],
dense_rank() over (order by num) as [DENSE_RANK]
from #SampleTable
```

Answer (score 0):

On a side note. You can think of ROW_NUMBER() as a running total of your rows. You can see that they both do the same thing:

```
WITH numbers AS (SELECT f.G, f.N FROM (VALUES (1,1),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,5)) AS f(G,N))
SELECT 
  NbrGroup = f.G,
  OldNbr   = f.N,
  NewNbrRN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.G ORDER BY f.N),
  NewNbrC  = COUNT(*)     OVER (PARTITION BY f.G ORDER BY f.N)
FROM numbers AS f;
```

**Results:**

```
NbrGroup    OldNbr      NewNbrRN             NewNbrC
----------- ----------- -------------------- -----------
1           1           1                    1
1           3           2                    2
1           4           3                    3
2           1           1                    1
2           5           2                    2
```

ROW_NUMBER() performs better which is why Developers don't use COUNT for this type of thing.